# How would you write a system of reccurence relations for this sum?

Tags: recurrence-relations

How would you write a system of reccurence relations and initial conditions, based on which it would be possible to evaluate the value of the expression without repeatedly evaluating the same intermediate values for this sum $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1+x+\dots+x^k}{k!+(k+1)!}$$

I defined
\begin{align}
S_0&=1/2, \\
S_k&=S_{k-1} + \frac{1+x+\dots+x^k}{k!k(k+1)!}, \quad k>0.
\end{align}
I'm not sure what I should do next. I mean I think I should define $a_k$ as maybe $\dfrac{1+x+\dots+x^k}{k!k(k+1)!}$ and express it through $a_{k-1}$ but... What do you think?

Comment: You should fix the expression, my guess is that the $=$ sign shouldn't be there.

Comment: Is it a sum or a product in the denominator? There seem to be conflicting evidence regarding this.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, i edited it.

Comment: You can condense the geometric sum at the numerators.

Comment: My question still stands.